# How exactly does Oraclize works under the hood?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, contract-design, oracles

The following is what the  [Ethereum documentation of Oraclize](http://docs.oraclize.it/#diams--ethereum) says:

> Firstly, in the most common case, a transaction executing a function
>   of a smart contract is broadcasted by an user. The function contains a
>   special instruction which manifest to Oraclize, who is constantly
>   monitoring the Ethereum blockchain for such instruction, a request for
>   data.
>
> Secondly, according to the parameters of such request, Oraclize will
>   fetch or compute a result, build, sign and broadcast the transaction
>   carrying the result. In the default configuration, such transaction
>   will execute the __callback function which should be placed in the
>   smart contract by its developer: for this reason, this transaction is
>   referred in the documentation as the Oraclize callback transaction.

What kind of instruction is executed? What messages are passed around when calling the `oraclize_query` function?

Is the "special" instruction and `oraclize_query` the same thing? As far as I understand, `oraclize_query` is the request for data, right?

The other answers, don't address what the "special" instruction is, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I found out in the comments at the question suggested by others to be the original one where the answers are that it actually does work the way I suggested (the events part was what I was unsure about)

I am not completely sure about this, but this is my assumption of how things work under the hood:

- when oraclize_query is invoked, it publishes an event with the data about what kind of query etc.
- oraclize monitors the blockchain and filters those events
- after finding out the answer, they send it to the contract that asked for it using __callback function (implemented by the requester)

This is the reason why it takes few blocks for the answer to be delivered.

I tried to confirm those assumptions by looking at [the code](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api), but got lost in it.

Comment: An event is just data in the blockchain, right? It is not a transaction/message?

Comment: exactly. it is a way of logging - http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#events

Comment: Why do they mention a special (invalid) instruction?

Comment: sorry, I don't get: who mentions a special or invalid instruction?

Comment: The Oraclize documentation for Ethereum API.

Comment: could you be more precise (give a link)? I tried searching for "invalid instruction" in the docs and found nothing

Comment: I meant "special instruction".